# Is the javascript in my webpart executing before the javascript in my MasterPage?

Tags: 2010, web-part, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper way to add jQuery to a MasterPage?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18068/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-jquery-to-a-masterpage)

I have a few webparts that use jQuery.  Instead of adding the jQuery in each web part I decided to add it in the masterpage.  The problem is that when I add the jQuery library from my masterpage instead of the webpart, all jQuery on my webpart stops working.  Is this because this javascript runs before javascript in my masterpage?  Is there a workaround for this?