# Include js file in Page Layout, after jQuery file in Master Page

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, master-page, page-layout

I'm trying to include a javascript file in my page layout file. I already have it inside the "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Content Placeholder, and it includes the file, however I need it to be included after the jQuery file that is included in my Master Page file. Otherwise I end up with javascript errors because '$' hasn't been declared yet.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: what does your master page code look like that is doing the jQuery include?

Comment: I answered this a couple years back: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18068/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-jquery-to-a-masterpage/18079#18079.  #2 of my answer should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Rob. I'm coming from a PHP development background, so onzur's solution of repositioning existing code, rather than adding more code, makes more sense to me.

Comment: That's only a recommended approach if you require that script across all pages.  The approach I suggested is recommended for page-specific scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the master page there is a place holder for the additionalpagehead . Make sure the jQuery reference Comes before that. that way the jQuery reference will be processed first

Answer (score 0):

My comment was a little vague and my answer to that other question didn't entirely address your situation.  You will want to reference Christian Glessner's write-up on SP SOD, with a focus on either registering your script to LoadAfterUI (should ensure jquery is loaded) or using the registerSodDep to register the dependency between your script and jquery if LoadAfterUI does not consistently produce the desired result.

I've used both for different solutions...either should work for you.  Note the requirement on the location of the script if you go the on-demand route.  As Christian suggests you should strongly name your script file if you're going to deploy it to the root of layouts.

http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html